# Understanding why SQL query is taking so long

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have a fairly large SQL query written. Below is a simplification of the issue i am seeing.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.MyTransactionDetails TDTL
    JOIN dbo.MyTransactions TRANS
       on TDTL.ID = TRANS.ID
    JOIN dbo.Customer CUST
       on TRANS.CustID = CUST.CustID
WHERE TDTL.DetailPostTime > CONVERT(datetime, '2015-05-04 10:25:53', 120) 
    AND TDTL.DetailPostTime < CONVERT(datetime, '2015-05-04 19:25:53', 120)
```

The MyTransactionDetails contains about 7 million rows and MyTransactions has about 300k rows.

The above query takes about 10 minutes to run which is insane. All indexes have been reindexed and there is an index on all the ID columns.

Now if i add the below lines to the WHERE clause the query the query takes about 1 second.

```
AND TRANS.TransBeginTime > CONVERT(datetime, '2015-05-05 10:25:53', 120) 
    AND TRANS.TransBeginTime < CONVERT(datetime, '2015-05-04 19:25:53', 120)
```

I know the contents of the database and the TransBeginTime is almost identical to the DetailPostTime so these extra where clauses shouldnt filter much more then the JOIN.

Why is the addition of these so much faster?

The problem is that i cannot use the filter on TransBeginTime as it is not guaranteed that the transaction detail will be posted on the same date.

EDIT: I should also add that the execution plan says that 50% of the time is taken up by MyTransactionDetails

Comment: @dan08, it is Sql Server

Comment: Do'h. missed that. Is there something analogous to EXPLAIN?

Comment: do you have an index on DetailPostTime?

Comment: What if you try with inner join? What if you first join MyTransactions and then MyTransactionDetails? Which version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: @dan08 What do you mean "analogous". analogous to what?

Comment: @dan08, of course. Include Actual Execution Plan

Comment: @HingeSight INNER JOIN is functionally the same as JOIN. I tried swapping the two tables but it didnt make any difference. MSSQL 2008R2

Comment: Add index on DetailPostTime. This is the problem for sure

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Adding new indexes is not a possibility.

Comment: @CathalMF, then no other way, wait for 10 minutes

Comment: Why question is that it is my understanding that my filter of the MyTransactionDetails in the Where clause should take effect before the JOIN on the MyTransactions table! So why is it so much slower

Comment: @CathalMF, because ther is index on TransBeginTime

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Bingo. Thats it. There is in index on the TransBeginTime.

Comment: @CathalMF JOIN in SQL server means outer join. By using inner join you hint the server to only scan those lines which match the join condition. This could be something.

Anyway, if you do not have index on DetailPostTime, you have to use exactly this column and you are not in a position to add index, joins and projections are not of great help.
Or use TransBeginTime padded with a month and pray for the best.
Good luck!

Comment: @HingeSight That is not correct. JOIN is the same as INNER JOIN.

Comment: You're in a tough spot if you can't add an index. How often does this query need to be ran? How will it's results be used? Maybe you could periodically process some columns from this table into a separate table and index that one, or maybe use a temporary table with an index. Hacky, but maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The percentages shown in the plan (both estimated and actual) are *estimates* that are based on the assumption that estimated row counts are correct. On bad cases the percentages can be totally wrong, even so that 1% can actually be 95%.

To figure out what is actually happening, turn on "statistics io". That will tell you the logical I/O count per table -- and getting that down usually means that also the time goes down.

You can also look at the actual plan, and there's a lot of things that can cause slowness, like scans, sorts, key lookups, spools etc. If you include both statistics I/O and execution plan (preferably the actual xml, not just the picture) it is a lot easier to figure out what's going wrong.